# Match href value with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

My input is similar to this:

```
<a href="link">text</a> <a href="correctLink">See full summary</a>
```

From this string i want to get only `correctLink` (the link that has *See full summary* as text) .

I'm working with python, and i tried:

```
re.compile( '<a href="(.*?)">See full summary</a>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE )
```

but the only string i get with `findall()` is `link">text</a> <a href="correctLink`.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit your link pattern to non-quote characters:

```
re.compile('<a href="([^"]+?)">See full summary</a>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
```

giving:

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile('<a href="([^"]+?)">See full summary</a>', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
>>> patt.findall('<a href="link">text</a> <a href="correctLink">See full summary</a>')
['correctLink']
```

Better yet, use a proper HTML parser.

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), finding that link would be as easy as:

```
soup.find('a', text='See full summary')['href']
```

for an exact text match:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup('<a href="link">text</a> <a href="correctLink">See full summary</a>')
>>> soup.find('a', text='See full summary')['href']
u'correctLink'
```